# neo4j embedded scala example inserting nodes

Tags: scala, neo4j

I've been able to run the neo4j scala example using the batch insert with no problems.  However, when I try to create Nodes without the unsafe batch inserter, I get no errors but no inserts either.

Here's the sample code

```
private def insertNodes(label:String, data: Iterator[Map[String, String]]) = {
    val dynLabel: Label = DynamicLabel.label(label)
    val graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH)
    registerShutdownHook( graphDb )

    val tx = graphDb.beginTx()

      for (item <- data)  {
        val node: Node = graphDb.createNode(dynLabel)
        node.setProperty("item_id", data("item_id"))
        node.setProperty("title", data("title"))
      }

    tx.success
    graphDb.shutdown()

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to commit the transaction. I'm not sure the proper scala syntax, but you want something like:

```
val tx = graphDb.beginTx()

try {
    for (item <- data)  {
        val node: Node = graphDb.createNode(dynLabel)
        node.setProperty("item_id", data("item_id"))
        node.setProperty("title", data("title"))
    }
    tx.success
} catch {
    case e: Exception => tx.failure
} finally {
    tx.close
}
```

Comment: I get error: "value commit is not a member of org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction tx.commit()"

Comment: I edited my original comments. It should be `tx.close`

Comment: tx.close doesn't throw an error, but the database is still empty after it runs.  Not sure why it's not actually committing the nodes.  Is there a persist or save method I need to call on the nodes themselves? Using neo4j 2.0.1

Comment: No. You should open a transaction, perform your update, than do a `tx.success` and a `tx.close`. You might want to put a log link in the catch statement to make sure there isn't an exception being thrown.

Comment: no errors, nothing going to the catch block.  Examining the nodes in the loop, the in node object in the runtime does get assigned nodeids even, but after it runs, it doesn't seem to persist anything into the db.

Comment: Are you pointing to the same `DB_PATH`? How are you looking at the data in the DB?

Comment: Same db path is tested with the batchinserter methods and it works fine.  I browse the data by starting the neo4j server afterwards then  with a cypher query "MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 100" using the neo4j rest api ... which returns 0 nodes

Comment: Looks like it just started working when I copied and pasted the code again.. not sure what the change was.

Comment: Great to hear. Happy Graphing! :)